# Audio content sharing using Intent in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to implement content sharing functionality in my app for audio files and here is my code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    File file = new File(songData_new.song_path);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

But it's not working on Marshmallow devices. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you added READ and WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE run-time permission asking before calling the intent ?

Comment: yes already added